# Papa Parse giving extra empty row when parsing CSV file

Tags: javascript, csv, parsing

Just found Papa Parse home page, trying to learn to use it.  Overall, things look pretty nice, easy to use.

I created a super-simple worksheet in Excel: three columns, first row being a header row naming the columns, and then three data rows, saved the spreadsheet in CSV format. opened that CSV file, it has 4 lines, just as I would expect.

Created a web page to run Papa.parse, dumped results to console.log, just like the example:

```
(5) [Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(1)]
0 : (3) ["Column A", "Column B", "Column C"]
1 : (3) ["Row 1, Col A", "Row 1, Col B", "Row 1, Col C"]
2 : (3) ["Row 2, Col A", "Row 2, Col B", "Row 2, Col C"]
3 : (3) ["Row 3, Col A", "Row 3, Col B", "Row 3, Col C"]
4 : [""]
```

I'm quite happy to see my data here, laid out as I would expect except for the 5th array there. That just seems "extra", "spurious", "wrong".

Not a big deal, certainly - I can deal with that. But I'm guessing that the extra array with an empty string isn't really "by design" is it? Why not just give the first 4 arrays?

For reference, here is the file input on my web page:

```
<input type="file" id="csvFile" oninput="readCsvFile('csvFile')">
```

And here is my callback function that gave the data above:

```
function readCsvFile(fileElId) {
    var
        fileEl = document.getElementById(fileElId),
        csvFile = fileEl.files[0];

    // Parse local CSV file
    Papa.parse(csvFile, {
        complete: function(results) {
            console.log("Finished:", results.data);
        }
    });
}
```

Anybody else seeing similar behavior? Does this qualify as a bug, or is there some good reason (i.e., documented reason?) to have that last, empty string array?

Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[This is an open issue on Papa Parse's Github repo.](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/issues/447) `skipEmptyLines: true` is noted as a workaround.

Comment: 'skipEmptyLines' noted, tested, verified. Thanks for your reply! ;)